# Handling UI frontend permissions with API backend

Tags: api, user-interface, architecture, permissions, frontend

I would like to ask for your advice about permissions system architecture. 
I have web UI as a separate frontend project and API as backend.

On API side permissions are defined for each controller/action as a certain enum with conformity to a number and when I want to create some role - I assign the set of those enums numbers that represent permissions and put them in a JWT token. Later an authorized client sends JWT token in header (Bearer token) and when API is going to invoke certain action - it checks if JWT token contains that enum value (number) that this controller/action is marked. On this side it is easy and working. The good point here is that during authorization we just get the set of ‘numbers’ from the database according to the role and filter access during access itself - so it works fast.

I was thinking of UI logic as of following - user fills login/password at UI side. UI sends credentials to API, API authenticates user, gather subset of permissions + some additional data and encrypts it to a JWT token - UI gets this token and encapsulates it inside cookie (may be + some own information) that is sent to client. So, each time client visits any UI page it sends cookies to UI, and UI gets JWT token from cookie makes API request.

However, in this scenario JWT token is encrypted and UI cannot know the data inside. And moreover, even if it could see data - it would give nothing as well as knowing the set of dynamic roles of API side would not give any information for UI side. Along with encoded ‘numbers’ that are converted to permissions in a real-time only on API side.

The question is how should webUI know if it should render access to admin page for a certain user or not. Or show additional UI options etc.

I think that this question might be trivial, as a lot of systems are split as UI + backend. However I have not found yet any good design explanation regardless.

Hope to get advices from community here. Thanks for ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally came up with the solution.
API should support external application registration. After that external application sends all operations (the list) that it supports to API. API stores that list.
And when we need to assign some permission for end user inside UI - we assign some particular operation to API role.

So - we have a single point of permission handling and the retrieved list is as abstract, as API permissions.

As result:
user -> sends authentication info to UI -> UI resends it to API -> API issues and encrypts JWT with own permissions and returns the list of permissions for requesting external app (UI) -> UI encapsulates permissions to cookies and after that can see what user is entitled to when user accesses UI

Answer (score 0):

@Oleksii, Your assumption is correct, when user logs in, UI wont be knowing about the details. So it will sent the credentials to API which authenticates it and information of roles and info will be shared by the API to UI, based on  roles segregated, UI will render the page if it has to be admin or normal user. Now this can be either in same api or separate api where once authentication passes to get the role details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But according to this scenario API should assign UI role on API side? However, if there would be some more UI apps - like Web, Mobile, Desktop - in this scenario API should send exact information about what that UI can do. That means higher coupling. And also it would not be possible to create new UI app without modifying API (in case we want UI to be able to handle access dynamically based on roles).